# AMDGPU-pro does not work properly on hybrid cards machine

Tags: 16.04, drivers, radeon, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

[amdgpu-pro-17.10](https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ubuntu/amdgpu-pro-17.10-401251.tar.xz)

Why does this latest version of AMD GPU driver still not work properly on my hybrid (Intel/AMD) cards laptop? EVery time it boots up, the fan starts to spins up like crazy, and the screen throws me outputs like this:

`[drm:amdgpu_fill_buffer [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Trying to clear memory with ring turned off.`

I'm pretty sure my hardware (AMD Radeon™ R7 M265) is listed in their AMD Product Family Compatibility section, and they explicitly claim on the website that it supports Ubuntu 16.04.2 (64-bit version), the requirement that I also meet for sure. How exactly should I approach this issue?

Comment: Just go into this knowing that dual GPU support in Linux is terrible at best, and absolute trash at worst...